# read and retain SQL data for use outside of class

Tags: c#

once again during my learning process here, I have run up against a wall. 
Basically I am reading a record from a Database and assigning it to a variable so that I can use it later on a form. 
below is a cut of the code I am using:

```
    public static class Configuration
{
    public static string ConfigurationFile { get; set; }
    public static string day_BackEnable { get; set; }
    public static string Day_BackTime { get; set; }
    public static string day_FileKeep { get; set; }
    public static string day_NotifyIcon { get; set; }
    public static string day_Error { get; set; }


    static Configuration()
    {
        ConfigurationFile = @"C:\testapp\cfg\testapp.sdf";
        ReadConfigFile();
    }

    public static void Reload()
    {
        ReadConfigFile();
    }

    private static void ReadConfigFile()
    {
        string day_BackEnable = "";
        string Day_BackTime = "";
        string day_FileKeep = "";
        string day_Error = "";
        string day_NotifyIcon = "";

        SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source =" + ConfigurationFile + "; Password =****"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from n_BackupMain";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    day_BackEnable = (reader[9].ToString());
                    Day_BackTime = (reader[11].ToString());
                    day_FileKeep = (reader[10].ToString());
                    day_NotifyIcon = (reader[12].ToString());
                    day_Error = (reader[13].ToString());
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

then I am just calling it to a message box like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(day_filekeep);
```

however when it displays it displays blank, like it's not reading from the class. I tried a message box right after reading the DB and it's picking the correct value out, it's just not passing it out for use elsewhere. Please what am I doing wrong or missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is you've assigned class members and local variables with the same names.**

When you do this, *the assignment will default to the local variable first*, the ones inside your `ReadConfigFile` method.

To fix the issue, just get rid of the variables declared in your `ReadConfigFile` method and then the `static` members on your actual class will get populated.

Here's a quick example of how this works:

```
public class Test
{
    static string test = ""; // class member

    public void TestTest()
    {
        // if you comment the below declaration out, 
        // then the right "test" will be assigned
        string test = "";  // local member 
        test = "hello"; // the local member is being assigned, not the class member
    }

    public void  GetTest()
    {
        // This will print "test is: [blank]" because the class member 
        // "test" was never assigned to
        Console.WriteLine("Test is:" + test); ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here one error you have 2 times:
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    SqlDataReader dbReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
      //if reader has row values
       if (dbReader.HasRows) // while(xxx) for more rows return
        {
           //READ DATA
        }